# WPF closing context menu before open new window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I have a WPF window which use heavy library and takes time to be fully rendered.
This library is in an `UserControl`.

This window is open by a context menu command in the parent window.

Using MVVM pattern, I need to get the DialogResult of this new window when closing to access the viewmodel.

When clicking the context menu item to open this new window, the context menu stays open until the instanciation of the new window will be done.

What can I do to close the context menu before open this window?

Here is the code refactored with the help of BionicCode:

**MAIN WINDOW XAML**

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="100" Width="100">
    <Image.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Open Window"
                Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}"
                />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Image.ContextMenu>
</Image>
```

**MAIN WINDOW**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RoutedCommand ShowMyDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("ShowMyDialogCommand", typeof(MainWindow));
    private readonly MainVM myMainVM;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myMainVM = new MainVM();
        DataContext = myMainVM;

        var showMyDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowMyDialogCommand, ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand);
        this.CommandBindings.Add(showMyDialogCommandBinding);

    }

    private void CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;
    
    private void ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewerVM vm = new ViewerVM();

        var okDialog = new OkDialog()
        {
            Title = "Viewer Dialog",
            DataContext = vm
        };

        bool? dialogResult = okDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (dialogResult == true)
        {
            this.myMainVM.HandleData(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAIN VM**

```
public class MainVM : ObservableObject
{
    private string myImagePath;

    public MainVM()
    {
        myImagePath = "flower.jpg";
    }

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return myImagePath; }
        set
        {
            if (myImagePath == value) return;
            myImagePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImagePath));
        }
    }

    public void HandleData(ViewerVM viewModel)
    {
        //Do stuffs
    }
}
```

**NEW WINDOW XAML**

```
<Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <!-- Dynamic content row -->
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <!-- Static content row (ok  and cancel buttons etc.) -->
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Dynamic content -->
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />

            <!-- Static content -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Content="Ok" IsDefault="True" Command="{x:Static local:OkDialog.OkCommand}" />
                <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Template>
```

**NEW WINDOW**

```
public partial class OkDialog : Window
{
    public static RoutedCommand OkCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("OkCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

    public OkDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var okCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(OkDialog.OkCommand, ExecuteOkCommand, CanExecuteOkCommand);
        this.CommandBindings.Add(okCommandBinding);

        this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    // If there is no explicit Content set, use the DataContext
    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) => this.Content = e.NewValue;

    private void CanExecuteOkCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
      => e.CanExecute = (this.DataContext as IOkDialogVM).CanExecuteOkCommand() ? true : false;
    private void ExecuteOkCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
      => this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

```
interface IOkDialogVM
{
    bool CanExecuteOkCommand();
}
```

**UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContextMenuTest.Viewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:ddes="http://schemas.devdept.com/winfx/2008/xaml/control"
             xmlns:ddgr="http://schemas.devdept.com/winfx/2008/xaml/graphics"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ddes:Design x:Name="myDesigner" Height="300" Width="300">
            <ddes:Design.Viewports>
                <ddes:Viewport>
                    <ddes:Viewport.Background>
                        <ddgr:BackgroundSettings StyleMode="Solid" TopColor="White"/>
                    </ddes:Viewport.Background>
                </ddes:Viewport>
            </ddes:Design.Viewports>
        </ddes:Design> 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class Viewer : UserControl
{
    public Viewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
public class ViewerVM : ObservableObject, IOkDialogVM
{
    public bool CanExecuteOkCommand() => true;
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewerVM}">
        <local:Viewer/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: I can only guess at this point (no implementation details are provided), but it's very likely that you have polluted the constructor with heavy load. You need to clean up your instantiation routine. The constructor must return immediately - always. Use the Loaded event to run long running initialization routines. Using the event handler also enables the use of asynchronous code. Constructor is only meant to initialize instance members to a reasonable default and to configure the instance.

Comment: *"The library which takes time to instanciate is a control"* - please show what exactly is going on. If it is another control that blocks you must show the related code so tat we can review in order to suggest improvements.

Comment: @BionicCode, thanks to not down vote my question. When the command OpenWindowCommandAction is executed, the context menu remains open. I want to close it, eventually change cursor to wait cursor, wihtout waiting the new window is displayed

Comment: I understand what you want. But it looks like you are blocking the UI. Your constructor takes too long. You said it's because of the instantiation of a child control. You have to fix this because this is what seems to cause the problem. But I can't help to fix it without knowing the details. I can only review what I can see, if that makes sense. I need to see the blocking control and how you load it. Otherwise, how can I suggest a fix?

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for your patience, I edited the question with more details

Comment: Thank you. But what you are doing is not MVVM. What tutorial gave you the idea to instantiate controls in your view model class? You should definitely find another tutorial and start to learn and understand MVVM from scratch. MVVM is a design pattern that was meant to avoid this exact scenario. Controls are views and they belong to the View in MVVM and not to the View Model. Why are you creating the view in the view model in the first place and why don't you simply add it to your XAML code of the NewWindow?

Comment: Where do create PartEditVM?

Comment: In MVVM the view model won't close (and open) any window. Let the Window close itself by simply adding a click event handler which then calls Window.Close. Then show the dialog from a code-behind click handler as well. The  View Model in MVVM should have absolutely no idea of the concept of controls. For the View Model there are no windows, dialogs, DataGrids and other kind of views. For the View Model there is only data.

Comment: For example, you create a data model instance in your view model and assign it to a property that you bind to a ContentControl.Content property. Then define a DataTemplate for the ContentControl.ContentTemplate in order to show the view that is associated with the data model. This way all the view code remains in the View and the View Model can continue to care about data only.

Comment: You are absolutely right about MVVM pattern, I just edited the code with the original one. I made several tests to just understand what was going wrong. Anyway, the orginal problem remains

Comment: Now this code looks more sensible although still wrong. But you still didn't answer why you define the DesignerView in C' instaed of ading it to the StackPanel directly in XAML? And where is AddItemCommandAction defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code breaks the MVVM design pattern. This is because you are managing views in your View Model. The view model class has no idea that the view will show a dialog. It therefore doesn't participate in any dialog flow.

You control the dialog completely in the View. You show it and you close it without any dependency on a view model class.

When you make use of the `Button.IsCancel` property the `Window` will close itself without the need to attach any event handler or close commands to this `Button`.

Setting the `Window.DialogResult` will always close the Window and let the `Window.ShowDialog` return the `Window.DialogResult`. You only need to attach an event handler to set the `Window.DialogResult` to `true` or `false`.
`Window` will take care of the rest. It's as easy as it can get. No View Model needed.

To show a dialog in an MVVM application, you can follow the below examples in the sections: *MVVM compliant dialog flow* and *Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow*.

To fix the loading experience, you shouldn't create any views in the constructor. Only do some light work in the constructor so that the constructor can return fast.

As a general rule, you should always avoid creating controls in your code-behind to add them manually to the visual tree. This is done in XAML, which wouldn't cause your current issue in the first place.

If you really need to do it your way, chose to create the views either in the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event or override the `FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate` method.
Because of the heavy load, I suggest to move your code to the `Loaded` event handler.

It's unclear what your `DesignView` constructor is exactly doing. In case you have shown the complete constructor and the timing of the call of the following line

```cs
devDept.LicenseManager.Unlock(typeof(devDept.Eyeshot.Workspace), "mykey");
```

doesn't matter or can be deferred, you should move this line to the `Loaded` event handler too. Just in case `LicenseManager.Unlock` is the blocking piece.

```cs
public partial class PartEditView : UserControl
{
  private DesignerView myDesignerView;

  public PartEditView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Follow this pattern to unlock the DesignerView.
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }
 
  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.myDesignerView = new DesignerView();
    this.myDesignerContainer.Children.Add(myDesignerView);
  }
}
```

### MVVM compliant dialog flow

The idea is simple, your View is responsible to show the dialog. Data is displayed/collected by binding elements to a dedicated view model of the dialog. After the dialog was closed, the View can interact with the View Model to pass over the data. In most scenarios the view model of the dialog knows how to handle the data (for example how to use the Model to persist data).

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**
The view model class has no idea that the view will show a dialog.
It doesn't participate in any dialog flow.
If the view model must handle the data collected by a dialog, the responsible view can pass the data to the view model.

```cs
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Such a public method is one possible way to allow the view to pass data
  // to this instance. Simply use the common means to send data from View to View Model.
  public void HandleData(MyDialogViewModel viewModel)
  {
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand ShowMyDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("ShowMyDialogCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  private MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainWindowViewModel;

    var showMyDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowMyDialogCommand, ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(showMyDialogCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;
  private void ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var myDialogViewModel = new MyDialogViewModel();
    var myDialog = new MyDialog() 
    { 
      Content = "I'm a dialog",
      DataContext = myDialogViewModel 
    };

    bool? dialogResult = myDialog.ShowDialog();

    // Do something when the user has closed the dialog e.g. using the 'OK' button
    if (dialogResult == true)
    {
      // Pass the dialog data (if it has some) to the view model class
      // for further processing. The data is stored via data binding in the     
      // myDialogViewModel (the DataContext of the dialog).
      // Depending on the context of the dialog, the dialog's view model
      // knows what to do with the data (e.g. save it to a database using the Model).
      this.MainWindowViewModel.HandleDialogData(myDialogViewModel);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Because the `ContextMenu` will have its own visual tree (it uses a `Popup` to display content), the routed command must be executed in the visual tree of the parent Window. For this reason we must explicitly set the `MenuItem.CommandTarget` property to point to the visual tree outside of the `ContextMenu`. The `CommandTarget` will therefore point to the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` (which is the `Image` in the example). The `Image` is an element of the `Window` visual tree where the `CommandBinding` is defined.
This is only necessary when the routed command is used inside a `Popup` (for example `ContextMenu`).
Otherwise setting the `CommandTarget` is not necessary.

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <!-- CommandTarget is not needed when the ICommandSource is part of the parent Window's visual tree -->
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}" />

    <Image>
      <Image.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>

          <!-- Visual tree is different from the Window (due to the Popup). 
               Set CommandTarget to allow the command to traverse the visual tree 
               of the MainWindow to reach to the CommandBindng (defined by the MainWindow) -->
          <MenuItem Header="Open Window" 
                    Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource     
AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
        </ContextMenu>
      </Image.ContextMenu>
    </Image>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MyDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MyDialog : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void OkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Setting the DialogResult will automatically close the Window
    // and return the DialogResult value.
    this.DialogResult = true;
  }
}
```

**MyDialog.xaml**
It's important to set `Button.IsCancel` to `true` for the "Cancel" button.
This allows the `Window` to close itself automatically.
Closing the `Window` in case of the "Ok" button being clicked is achieved by setting the `Window.DialogResult` property from a `Button.Click` handler (or RoutedCommand). Window  will always close itself when `Window.DialogResult` is set.

```xml
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition /> <!-- Content row -->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Dialog button row -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
               Text="I'm a custom dialog" />

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
      <Button Content="Ok"
              IsDefault="True"
              Click="OkButton_Click"/>
      <Button Content="Cancel"
              IsCancel="True" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

### Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow

A more advanced version will make use of the fact that the `Window` is a `ContentControl`. This means we can define the content based on a data model (like the above `MyDialogViewModel`) and load the associated view by defining a `DataTemplate`, preferably implicit (without the `x:Key` directive defined). This makes the dialog highly reusable and easy to deal with in an MVVM context.

The following example defines a dialog that only knows how to handle an "Ok" and "Cancel" button. But through data templating the same class can show all kind of views.

**IOkDialogViewModel.cs**

```cs
interface IOkDialogViewModel
{
  bool CanExecuteOkCommand();
}
```

**OkDialogViewModel.cs**
Example data model that is mapped to a dedicated view via a `DataTemplate`
that makes the content of the dialog.

```cs
// Consider to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo
public class OkDialogViewModel : IOkDialogViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string SomeText { get; set; }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
  public bool CanExecuteOkCommand() => this.SomeText.StartsWith("@");
}
```

**OkDialog.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class OkDialog : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand OkCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("OkCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  public OkDialog()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    var okCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(OkDialog.OkCommand, ExecuteOkCommand, CanExecuteOkCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(okCommandBinding);

    this.DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
  }

  // If there is no explicit Content set, use the DataContext
  private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) => this.Content ??= e.NewValue;

  private void CanExecuteOkCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = (this.DataContext as IOkDialogViewModel)?.CanExecuteOkCommand() ?? true;
  private void ExecuteOkCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => this.DialogResult = true;
}
```

**OkDialog.xaml**
Now hardcode the default content (the "Ok" and "Close" buttons) into the `Window.Template`. This will make the static content.
The dynamic content is implicitly created by the client who defined a `DataTemplate` for the `Window.Content`.

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition /> <!-- Dynamic content row -->
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Static content row (ok  and cancel buttons etc.) -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Dynamic content -->
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />

        <!-- Static content -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
          <Button Content="Ok"
                  IsDefault="True"
                  Command="{x:Static local:OkDialog.OkCommand}" />
          <Button Content="Cancel"
                  IsCancel="True" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Template>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**
Define a `DataTemplate` to crate the particular dialog view that is associated with the `OkDialogViewModel`.

```xml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OkDialogViewModel}">
      <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand ShowMyDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("ShowMyDialogCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  private MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainWindowViewModel;

    var showMyDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowMyDialogCommand, ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(showMyDialogCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;
  private void ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Because the text doesn't start with '@', the OK button will be disabled later,
    // until the user fixes the input in the TextBox.
    var dialogViewModel = new OkDialogViewModel() { SomeText = "Just some text" };

    var okDialog = new OkDialog() 
    { 
      Title = "I'm an Ok dialog", 
      DataContext = dialogViewModel
    };

    bool? dialogResult = okDialog.ShowDialog();

    // Do something when the user has closed the dialog e.g. using the 'OK' button
    if (dialogResult == true)
    {
      // Pass the dialog data (if it has some) to the view model class
      // for further processing. The data is stored via data binding in the     
      // DataContext/Content of the dialog.
      // Depending on the context of the dialog, the dialog's view model
      // knows what to do with the data (e.g. save it to a database using the Model).
      this.MainWindowViewModel.HandleData(dialogViewModel);
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**
Because the `ContextMenu` will have its own visual tree (it uses a `Popup` to display content), the routed command must be executed in the visual tree of the parent Window. For this reason we must explicitly set the `MenuItem.CommandTarget` property to point to the visual tree outside of the `ContextMenu`. The `CommandTarget` will therefore point to the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` (which is the `Image` in the example). The `Image` is an element of the `Window` visual tree where the `CommandBinding` is defined.
This is only necessary when the routed command is used inside a `Popup` (for example `ContextMenu`).
Otherwise setting the `CommandTarget` is not necessary.

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <!-- CommandTarget is not needed when the ICommandSource is part of the parent Window's visual tree -->
    <Button Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}" />

    <Image>
      <Image.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>

          <!-- Visual tree is different from the Window (due to the Popup). 
               Set CommandTarget to allow the command to traverse the visual tree 
               of the MainWindow to reach to the CommandBindng (defined by the MainWindow) -->
          <MenuItem Header="Open Window" 
                    Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource     
AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
        </ContextMenu>
      </Image.ContextMenu>
    </Image>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

### Update

It turns out that the origin is really the 3rd party library. The implementation of the control is obviously really bad. It freezes the UI during construction/loading which is unacceptable.

Because the UI is frozen you can't even show a busy indicator. The user is left to believe that the application has crashed.
Such a library would make me doubt the authors skills and experience.
Because of the serious impact on the application's performance and UX I recommend to find an alternative library.

Even closing the `ContextMenu` forcefully does not solve the problem of a bad UX as the application still hangs.

The following solution extends the previous *"Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow"* example. Following the *"Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow"* will give you a clean design that helps to solve the issue more "gracefully" (I still recommend to find a better library).
The solution implements the following flow:

- Instead of opening the dialog (which contains the terrible control) directly on clicking the `MenuItem`, we modify the flow to first close the `ContextMenu`.
  This is accomplished by registering a `ContextMenu.Opened` event handler.
- Next we spawn a second UI thread. Because any busy indicator that runs in the primary UI thread would freeze too, we use this dedicated new UI thread to show a busy indicator dialog. This way we can improve the UX significantly as from the user's point of view everything appears to be under control: just some heavy loading in the background.
- In the main UI tread we create the instance of the dialog which is known to freeze the application (which will still freeze)
- We use a `SemaphoreSlim` to allow the busy indicator dialog to wait asynchronously for a signal from the main UI thread in order to continue.
- After the busy indicator thread received the signal, the busy indicator will close itself and shut down the second UI thread
- The dialog cantaining the 3rd party control is now ready to use.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Image>
    <Image.ContextMenu>
      <ContextMenu Closed="OnImageContextMenuClosed">

        <!-- Visual tree is different from the Window (due to the Popup). 
             Set CommandTarget to allow the command to traverse the visual tree 
             of the MainWindow to reach to the CommandBindng (defined by the MainWindow) -->
        <MenuItem Header="Open Window" 
                  Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ShowMyDialogCommand}"
                  CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource     
AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
      </ContextMenu>
    </Image.ContextMenu>
  </Image>  
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static RoutedCommand ShowMyDialogCommand { get; } = new RoutedCommand("ShowMyDialogCommand", typeof(MainWindow));

  private MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.MainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = this.MainWindowViewModel;

    var showMyDialogCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ShowMyDialogCommand, ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand, CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(showMyDialogCommandBinding);
  }

  private void CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;

  // Only close the ContextMenu. The ContextMenu.Closed event will continue the flow.
  private void ExecuteShowMyDialogCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).ContextMenu.IsOpen = false;

  private void OnImageContextMenuClosed(object? sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Create a semaphore that is initially blocking.
    // The semaphore is used to signal the new UI thread that it must shut down
    // and close the busy indicator dialog.
    using var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    var uiThread = new Thread(state => ShowBusyIndicator(semaphore))
    {
      IsBackground = false
    };
    uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    uiThread.Start();
    
    (bool IsOk, OkDialogViewModel ViewModel) dialogResult = ShowOkDialog(semaphore);

    // Do something when the user has closed the dialog e.g. using the 'OK' button
    if (dialogResult.IsOk)
    {
      //dialogResult.ViewModel
    }
  }

  private void ShowBusyIndicator(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
  {
    // Consider to create a dedicated BusyIndicatorDialog class (following the pattern of the OkDialog).
    // This allows to create a DataTemplate to design the dialog using XAML.
    var busyIndicator = new Window() 
    { 
      Content = new ProgressBar() { IsIndeterminate = true },
      Title = "Loading, please wait..."
    };

    // Let the busy indicator dialog wait for the SemaphoreSlim to signal.
    // Consider to move this code directly to a dedicated BusyIndicatorDialog class.

    // In case of implementing a dedicated BusyIndicatorDialog, consider to implement a special event which allows more control over the timing of the event (to replace the Loaded event).
    busyIndicator.Loaded += (s, e) => OnBusyIndicatorLoaded(busyIndicator, semaphore);
    busyIndicator.Show();

    Dispatcher.Run();
  }

  // Use the Dispatcher of the busy indicator Window to post the code to the second UI thread.
  private void OnBusyIndicatorLoaded(Window busyIndicator, SemaphoreSlim semaphore) 
  {
     _ = busyIndicator.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
    {
      // Wait for the signal to continue the thread.
      await semaphore.WaitAsync();

      busyIndicator.Close();
      busyIndicator.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
  }

  private (bool IsOk, OkDialogViewModel ViewModel) ShowOkDialog(SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
  {
      var dialogViewModel = new OkDialogViewModel() { SomeText = "Just some text" };
      var myDialog = new OkDialog() 
      { 
        Title = "I'm a Ok dialog", 
        DataContext = dialogViewModel 
      };

      // Signal the busy indicator thread to continue (it will close itself and shut down the thread)
      _ = semaphore.Release();

      bool dialogResult = myDialog.ShowDialog() ?? false;
      return (dialogResult, dialogViewModel);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow solution. But it seems that the MainWindow CanExecuteShowMyDialogCommand method is never called and the ContextMenu item remains disabled

Comment: I have fixed it. Take a look at the MenuItem in the example: I've set the CommandTarget to force the routed command to execute in the visual tree of the parent Window. The reason is that the content of the ContextMenu is part of its own visual tree (because it uses a Popop to display the menu items). The command bindings are defined in the visual tree of the parent Window. You can use the MenuItem.Click event to register a click handler in code-behind if you find this more convenient. The ContextMenu is a special case because of its own visual tree.

Comment: The CommandTarget is set to the PlacementTarget of the ContextMenu. Following your example, the PlacementTarget is the Image. Because the Image is a child of the MainWindow visual tree, the command binding defined in MainWindow can now handle the routed command. It can execute CanExecute to enable the MeniItem.

Comment: Thanks for the MVVM template to open windows, really nice. I applied it to my original question and moved the time consuming control into the xaml (this time a UserControl in a DataTemplate located in App.xaml) but the problem remains

Comment: Have you read the part about my suggestion to defer the authentication part? When you comment the related line out of the constructor from the DesignerView,  does the control load fast again?

Comment: I also suggested to defer the creation of the DesignerView. In my example I moved the instantiation to the Loaded event handler (I still wonder why you dont't define it in XAML instead of adding it manually to the Grid. Or have you changed the instantiation routine to something different? Did I understand you correctly that you now create DesignerView in XAML? If so, then please try to comment out the authentication line `devDept.LicenseManager.Unlock...`

Comment: I did, the authentification is in the OnLoaded method, I tried also without auth, same result

Comment: I see. But the constructor of DesignerView is quite boring. Only event handler registration. Nothing that takes long to execute. Are you missing something?

Comment: What is myDesigner.SetView doing? Can you comment it out to see if the constructor returns faster?

Comment: And what makes you believe that the DesignerView construction is the cause for the slow loading experience? Have you debugged the constructor to see where the execution "hangs"?

Comment: Right now, the DesignerView is defined in xaml, as you said. It was instanciated in the code behind because I need its reference to send commands to the control. But it's not a problem anymore now with the new MVVM template.

Comment: Can you comment out the SoftDesign control (in XAML)? Maybe it's this control that delays loading?

Comment: I have simplified the code to the maximum, only instanciation of the Designer, no sets anymore, nothing. I know that it is this control that takes time because there is nothing else in my UserControl. To make tests with minimal code, I got your answer Advanced MVVM compliant dialog flow and replaced your view with a Textbox by mine with only the Designer control

Comment: Have you removed the SoftDesign control too?

Comment: all the code has been updated (from the very begining of the question), I can see that the instantiation is long at the first opening, and then faster but never smooth

Comment: The only unknown component now is the ddes:Design control. Have you followed my recommendation to remove this control to test if the Viewer opens faster?

Comment: I did, when I remove the control the window opens instantly

Comment: Then the origin of bad performance is not the Viewer control. Instead of optimizing the Viewer you must optimize the Design control. But I assume it's a 3rd party library control? Maybe the control exposes some properties that allow to configure it in order to improve the performance? Also with your new improved implementation does the context menu closes immediately or do you still have to wait until the Design control is completely loaded?

Comment: Indeed, it's a 3rd party library and I can't do anything. The original problem was that the contextmenu doesn't close until the Design control is fully loaded, this problem is still there. This is why I asked at the very begining if there is a way to close the contextmenu even if the opened window is not completly rendered

Comment: You should really try to find a different library that does not freeze your application. I have updated my answer to extend it with a solution that gracefully solves the problem of the freezing application (see the *Update* section). It's the best possible solution as we don't have access to the 3rd party library. All we can do is to improve the user experience by closing the ContextMenu and by displaying a busy indicator. This way the user won't think that the application has crashed (this is maybe the worst case in terms of UI design and UX design - a freezing UI).